# IntelliJ does not suggest "try/multi - catch" in context action

Tags: exception, intellij-idea

Im using IntelliJ with SDK8 and when I have a call of a method that possibly may throw an exception the context action offers only adding exception to method signature or regular surround with try/catch (like you can see on the picture). Do\ I have to write the could manually every time when I want to use the try/multi catch syntax with "|" operator and only one catch block? Or is the way to make IntelliJ do it automatically? I remeber it was suggested in the context action menu in Eclipse.

[context action menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gxv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7, multi-catch blocks are available. We have an inspection **Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 7 | Identical 'catch' branches in 'try' statement** which identifies identical catch blocks and suggests collapsing them to multi-catch. It's immediately available after doing 'Surround with':
[image]

So you only need to press additionally F2; Alt+Shift+Enter to get the desired result which is not more difficult than selecting an option from the submenu:

```java
try {
  methodThatThrowsFirstAndSecondException();
} catch (FirstException | SecondException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```